# How to hint Sympy an integration for Inverse Gaussian equation

Tags: python, distribution, sympy, symbolic-math

Symbolic integration of the Inverse Gaussian PDF works on Wolfram Alpha 
https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E(-3%2F2)*exp(-Bx-A%2Fx)

but I cannot reproduce it using Sympy (It takes forever with no response):

```
from __future__ import division
from sympy import *
A, B, x = symbols('A B x')
ig_pdf = (sqrt(x)**(-3))*exp(-B*x-A/x)
pprint(ig_pdf, use_unicode=True)
ig_cdf = integrate(ig_pdf, x, conds='none')
pprint(ig_cdf, use_unicode=True)
```

Is there a way to make it work and produce a closed form integration?
How can I hint Sympy to use a certain integration rule such as the "integration by parts"?

Comment: If you assign `A, B, x` as real valuables then sympy will eventually give up and simply return the unevaluated integral. Did take my computer quite a while.

Comment: If you just need to derive the CDF, it looks like it has a relatively simple form in terms of the the standard normal CDF. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_Gaussian_distribution

Comment: @Hannebambel; great. It's worth posting as an answer. Then I will mark it as the accepted answer.
When you say "eventually give up", what is it looking for which gives up? Any way to make it faster?

Thanks @RobertDodier; I need to use it for other cases. This is an example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As requested here my comment as an answer.

I assume sympy is not (yet) able to solve this integral. Assigning `A, B, x = symbols('A B x', real=True)` as real variables does not do the trick. sympy calculates for about 40 minutes before simply returning the integral, not the solution. The same output can be achieved much faster by using `ig_cdf = sym.integrals.Integral(ig_pdf, x)` instead of the integration. Tested with sympy version 1.1.1, python 3.6.2

Comment: Wolfram Alpha can do it on their server. I'm curious to see whether Mathematica (on a desktop PC) is able to do this integration. Wolfram vs Sympy: 1 0